Run Async methods on MauiProgram.cs
I need to run some async methods that will intercat with db (create admin user, etc). I want to run them on MauiProgram.cs, wondering whats the best way of doing it.The code below works, not sure if its the best way of doing so.
  public static MauiAppBuilder SqlLiteInitializer(this MauiAppBuilder mauiAppBuilder)
  {
      var sqlLite = mauiAppBuilder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<ISqlLite<UserModel>>();

      Task.Run(() => sqlLite.CreateOrUpdateTableAsync()).Wait();


Well, async method returns already a task, so it's just overhead to wrap it in yet anowther, instead you can do:
sqlLite.CreateOrUpdateTableAsync().Wait();


the problem is, if i just sqlLite.CreateOrUpdateTableAsync().Wait(); the program execution will freeze once it encounters the first await inside CreateOrUpdateTableAsync(), on the other hand with my example it doesnt, not sure why tho

@BernardoSousa That's because Task.Run will start work on other background thread, while SQL apparently block UI thread.
